# How to make a subform event independent of the main form's name

Tags: ms-access

I have three forms I am trying to link.  The fist is called "Selections", which includes a subform "Pending" which is linked to a field in "Selections".  This is working fine - when I select a group of records in "Selections" I get the appropriate records in "Pending".

"Pending" includes an ID field, which when clicked opens a new form (not a subform) called "Tax calendar".  Again, this works fine.  The event setting is an embedded macro to open "Tax calendar" when "[ID]=[Forms]![selections]![pending]![id]"

My problem is that I want several different "selections..." forms that will allow different ways to select records for the "Pending" subform.  Because the "Pending" subform event has to know which form it came from, "Pending" doesn't work from all of the various "Selection..." forms.

How can I make the event in "Pending" independent from the "Selections..." form that uses it as a subform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and avoid embedded macros, you get much more control with VBA. So instead of

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "TaxCalendar",,,"[ID]=" & [Forms]![selections]![pending]![id]
```

You can have

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "TaxCalendar",,,"[ID]=" & Me.Parent.[id]
```